# Save button has an extra )

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm saving the Background section, and the Save button looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed, typo during some recent CSS refactors.

Comment: CSS adding a character? That's weird... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Moving from using an MVC helper to a plain ol' HTML button: `@Html.Submit(_s("Save"))` ->  `<button type="submit" class="btn _primary">_s("Save"))</button>`. (note trailing `)`). Part of an effort to move Careers to a more standardized set of styles.

Comment: eh, classic. Bit more than just CSS (thought you mean changing stylesheets) but yeah, happens to the best. :-)